# How to hide some parts of URL part for custom page in wordpress

Tags: php, url-rewriting, wordpress, url-shortener

I am new in WordPress. I have created two custom pages in my wordpress plugin. When I am redirecting to those pages than URL is showing like this:

```
http://myDomainName.com/wp-content/plugins/camophoto/php-sdk/wp_mypage.php
```

and I want to show it like this:

```
http://myDomainName.com/wp_mypage.php
```

How can I hide the part???

```
wp-content/plugins/camophoto
```

I have a solution but not know how and where to use it??

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );  
function add_author_rules() {   
add_rewrite_rule(  
"camoPhoto.php/?",  
"wp-content/plugins/camophoto/php-sdk/camoPhoto.php",  
"top");
}
```

Please any body help me.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to install the plugin "*WP No Category Base*". If you dont want to do this, than there is another possibility.

If you have access to the `.htaccess` file you can change the direction.

First backup your `.htaccess` file. Now open and append the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/camophoto/(.+)$ http://myDomainName.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not working RewriteRule. I have tested in .htaccess file

Comment: How does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: the code is working in .htaccess file but not getting the required results

Comment: i want to change (http://test.aleemakhter.com/wp-content/plugins/camophoto/template/login.php) into (http://test.aleemakhter.com/login.php) but not getting the result.